# Workflow copy between libraries with column validation error

Tags: 2013, workflow, column, validation, copy-item

I get an issue when a workflow does a copy command.

> The workflow could not copy the item. Make sure the source and destination lists have the same columns and column settings.

Libraries are definitely the same!

The issue comes when destination library contains any field with validation. If I delete the rule for validation WF runs fine, but if any validation in there I got an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, let's get over it. The error report at on-premise solution was not so clear, but after test on cloud solution I've got an useful answer:

> This operation is not supported because the destination document library contains a list data validation formula or has the EnforceDataValidation property set.

***So if you plan moving with files, don't make a validation column in there.***

Validation should be done on front by javascript or user should fill meta data by tasks with column validation and workflow assigns tested values into. Or you can figure out your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possible causes for your issue and resolutions

Are you using 2010 WF or 2013 WF (I know the tag is 2013 but just to confirm which template you are using).

Anyhow this is what I found searching this issue:

- Do you copy list item action placed in Impersonation step? If so, the
  workflow will run with the account which you used to create the
  workflow. So the workflow will failed when the account don't have
  enough permission.
- If copy list item is not placed in Impersonation step, the workflow
  will run with the user make sure this user also have enough
  permission.

Comment: regards WF 2013 build under Nintex. it is all about copy command.  WF is made by and starts with full permissions. Like in question, if there no column validation is everything fine. the issue become when destination library has a column validation on field.  Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the only way is programmatically disable, copy file and enable validation.. e.g. http://pastebin.com/fn6AVfJ3